# Encrypt clear SQL Server password without changing the application

Tags: sql-server, delphi-7

I've been asked to evaluate the effort to secure a SQL Server user password, where the password is stored as clear text. The application that accesses to the SQL Server table is written in Delphi 7, but since we have to complain to GDPR, I've been asked to look for a solution that is almost 0 impact on the existing application.

Is there a way I can configure SQL Server so it acts out of the box without the need to change the app?

Otherwise, the idea I propose is to use a switch parameter that if set to true performs the secure authentication otherwise not.

For now, the `Password` column is just a `char(32)` column

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, but why would GDPR limit the changes to the application? Does the application handle the authentication (i.e. prompt user for username and password) and rely on clear text password database?

Comment: yes, currently all password are stored in clear, and from delphi application it performs a comparison between login's password and the stored one

Comment: The fix is needed in both the the databases and application you ***need*** to salt and hash those passwords, and that's needs help from both sides.

Comment: @advapi GDPR doesn't prevent you from fixing errors. It **demands** that you fix errors

Comment: @advapi and storing passwords in clear-text is a violation of all security guidelines. Should a data breach occur, you get to pay the maximum GDPR **and** local fines for willfully ignoring well-established security practices, like **never** storing the password in cleartext. In fact, even encryption isn't enough. The common practice is storing a hash of a salted password

Comment: @advapi in other words, if you don't change how the app works, you can't be GDPR compliant

Comment: `written in Delphi 7` password hashing or password encryption was used back then too. What changed is that password *encryption* and recovery is no longer considered secure, so all sites send you a reset link instead of your stored password

Comment: `almost 0 impact on the existing application` Just use *Windows authentication* then and get rid of all password storage issues. That's the most secure option too. In a Windows domain environment, this is trivial - just *remove* all code that handles passwords, add the `Trusted Connection` keyword to the connection string. You could use extra options like Azure AD authentication, but using a 16-yo unsupported Delphi version means those are probably not available

Comment: `almost 0 impact on the existing application` if you target work in a domain, you'll have to change the authentication code. If you're lucky, the authentication code will be isolated in a separate module you can modify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If taken on a face value, correct answer would be to refer you to [Always Encrypted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15).

That said, it's pretty powerful foot-gun in this context; it does not address the underlying issues that you still store the passwords in clear text. Only proper way to fix this issue is to start hashing the passwords. Whether that is possible or not without changing the application is impossible to say without seeing it, but I find it highly unlikely.